# How to calculate "relative error in the sum of squares" and "relative error in the approximate solution" from least squares method?

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares, levenberg-marquardt

I have implemented a 3D gaussian fit using [`scipy.optimize.leastsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html) and now I would like to tweak the arguments `ftol` and `xtol` to optimize the performances. However, I don't understand the "units" of these two parameters in order to make a proper choice. Is it possible to calculate these two parameters from the results? That would give me an understanding of how to choose them. My data is numpy arrays of `np.uint8`. I tried to read the FORTRAN source code of MINIPACK but my FORTRAN knowledge is zero. I also read checked the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm, but I could not really get a number that was below the `ftol` for example.

Here is a minimal example of what I do:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

class gaussian_model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prev_iter_model = None
        self.f_vals = []

    def gaussian_1D(self, coeffs, xx):
        A, sigma, mu = coeffs
        # Center rotation around peak center
        x0 = xx - mu
        model = A*np.exp(-(x0**2)/(2*(sigma**2)))
        return model

    def residuals(self, coeffs, I_obs, xx, model_func):
        model = model_func(coeffs, xx)
        residuals = I_obs - model
        if self.prev_iter_model is not None:
            self.f = np.sum(((model-self.prev_iter_model)/model)**2)
            self.f_vals.append(self.f)
        self.prev_iter_model = model
        return residuals


# x data
x_start = 1
x_stop = 10
num = 100
xx, dx = np.linspace(x_start, x_stop, num, retstep=True)

# Simulated data with some noise
A, s_x, mu = 10, 0.5, 3
coeffs = [A, s_x, mu]
model = gaussian_model()
yy = model.gaussian_1D(coeffs, xx)
noise_ampl = 0.5
noise = np.random.normal(0, noise_ampl, size=num)
yy += noise

# LM Least squares
initial_guess = [1, 1, 1]
pred_coeffs, cov_x, info, mesg, ier = leastsq(model.residuals, initial_guess,
                                              args=(yy, xx, model.gaussian_1D),
                                              ftol=1E-6, full_output=True)
yy_fit = model.gaussian_1D(pred_coeffs, xx)

rel_SSD = np.sum(((yy-yy_fit)/yy)**2)
RMS_SSD = np.sqrt(rel_SSD/num)

print(RMS_SSD)
print(model.f)
print(model.f_vals)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)

# Plot results
ax[0].scatter(xx, yy)
ax[0].plot(xx, yy_fit, c='r')

ax[1].scatter(range(len(model.f_vals)), model.f_vals, c='r')

# ax[1].set_ylim(0, 1E-6)

plt.show()
```

`rel_SSD` is around 1 and definitely not something below `ftol = 1E-6`.

EDIT: Based on @user12750353 answer below I updated my minimal example to try to recreate how [lmdif](https://www.netlib.org/minpack/lmdif.f) determines termination with `ftol`. The problem is that my `f_vals` are too small, so they are not the right values. The reason I would like to recreate this is that I would like to see what kind of numbers I am getting on my main code to decide on a `ftol` that would terminate the fitting process earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are giving a function without the gradient, the method called is [lmdif](https://www.netlib.org/minpack/lmdif.f). Instead of gradients it will use forward difference gradient estimate, `f(x + delta) - f(x) ~ delta * df(x)/dx` (I will write as if the parameter).

There you find the following description

```txt
c       ftol is a nonnegative input variable. termination
c         occurs when both the actual and predicted relative
c         reductions in the sum of squares are at most ftol.
c         therefore, ftol measures the relative error desired
c         in the sum of squares.
c
c       xtol is a nonnegative input variable. termination
c         occurs when the relative error between two consecutive
c         iterates is at most xtol. therefore, xtol measures the
c         relative error desired in the approximate solution.
```

Looking in the code the actual reduction `acred = 1 - (fnorm1/fnorm)**2` is what you calculated for `rel_SSD`, but between the two last iterations, not between the fitted function and the target points.

### Example

The problem here is that we need to discover what are the values assumed by the internal variables. An attempt to do so is to save the coefficients and the residual norm every time the function is called as follows.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

class gaussian_model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prev_iter_model = None
        self.fnorm = []
        self.x = []

    def gaussian_1D(self, coeffs, xx):
        A, sigma, mu = coeffs
        # Center rotation around peak center
        x0 = xx - mu
        model = A*np.exp(-(x0**2)/(2*(sigma**2)))
        grad = np.array([
            model / A,
            model * x0**2 / (sigma**3),
            model * 2 * x0 / (2*(sigma**2))
        ]).transpose();
        
        return model, grad

    def residuals(self, coeffs, I_obs, xx, model_func):
        model, grad = model_func(coeffs, xx)
        residuals = I_obs - model
        self.x.append(np.copy(coeffs));
        self.fnorm.append(np.sqrt(np.sum(residuals**2)))
        return residuals
    
    def grad(self, coeffs, I_obs, xx, model_func):
        model, grad = model_func(coeffs, xx)
        residuals = I_obs - model
        return -grad
    
    def plot_progress(self):
        x = np.array(self.x)
        dx = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.diff(x, axis=0)**2, axis=1))
        plt.plot(dx / np.sqrt(np.sum(x[1:, :]**2, axis=1)))
        fnorm = np.array(self.fnorm)
        plt.plot(1 - (fnorm[1:]/fnorm[:-1])**2)
        plt.legend(['$||\Delta f||$', '$||\Delta x||$'], loc='upper left');
        
# x data
x_start = 1
x_stop = 10
num = 100
xx, dx = np.linspace(x_start, x_stop, num, retstep=True)

# Simulated data with some noise
A, s_x, mu = 10, 0.5, 3
coeffs = [A, s_x, mu]
model = gaussian_model()
yy, _ = model.gaussian_1D(coeffs, xx)
noise_ampl = 0.5
noise = np.random.normal(0, noise_ampl, size=num)
yy += noise
```

Then we can see the relative variation of $x$ and $f$

```py
initial_guess = [1, 1, 1]
pred_coeffs, cov_x, info, mesg, ier = leastsq(model.residuals, initial_guess,
                                              args=(yy, xx, model.gaussian_1D),
                                              xtol=1e-6,
                                              ftol=1e-6, full_output=True)

plt.figure(figsize=(14, 6))
plt.subplot(121)
model.plot_progress()
plt.yscale('log')
plt.grid()
plt.subplot(122)

yy_fit,_ = model.gaussian_1D(pred_coeffs, xx)
# Plot results
plt.scatter(xx, yy)
plt.plot(xx, yy_fit, c='r')
plt.show()
```

The problem with this is that the function is evaluated both to compute `f` and to compute the gradient of `f`. To produce a cleaner plot what can be done is to implement pass `Dfun` so that it evaluate `func` only once per iteration.

```py
# x data
x_start = 1
x_stop = 10
num = 100
xx, dx = np.linspace(x_start, x_stop, num, retstep=True)

# Simulated data with some noise
A, s_x, mu = 10, 0.5, 3
coeffs = [A, s_x, mu]
model = gaussian_model()
yy, _ = model.gaussian_1D(coeffs, xx)
noise_ampl = 0.5
noise = np.random.normal(0, noise_ampl, size=num)
yy += noise

# LM Least squares
initial_guess = [1, 1, 1]
pred_coeffs, cov_x, info, mesg, ier = leastsq(model.residuals, initial_guess,
                                              args=(yy, xx, model.gaussian_1D),
                                              Dfun=model.grad,
                                              xtol=1e-6,
                                              ftol=1e-6, full_output=True)

plt.figure(figsize=(14, 6))
plt.subplot(121)
model.plot_progress()
plt.yscale('log')
plt.grid()
plt.subplot(122)

yy_fit,_ = model.gaussian_1D(pred_coeffs, xx)
# Plot results
plt.scatter(xx, yy)
plt.plot(xx, yy_fit, c='r')
plt.show()
```

[image: evolution plot]

Well, the value I am obtaining for xtol is not exactly what is in the `lmdif` implementation.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that is exactly the method that I tried to read and understand. If I understood correctly then I cannot choose `ftol` based on the magnitude of my target points, because it doesn't matter how big they are right? Anyway, I tried to recreate what I understood to get all the relative errors calculated for each iteration, but I get very small numbers and termination should have happened immediately. I updated the minimal example in my question. The values in `model.f_vals` are really small, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you seen the updated answer @Francesco

Comment: Yes I did, but I didn't have time to look at it! However the ||Df|| looks exactly like I would expect it, thank you very much!

Comment: Can I ask you why you are transposing `grad`?

Comment: The gradient expected is a matrix where `grad[i,j]` is the derivative of the output `i` wrt param `j`. I can wrote the analytic expression of the derivatives with respect to each of the three parameters. Then I applied to the vector of inputs. Since create a matrix where the row `j` is the derivative wrt param `j` I transpose it before passing returning it.

Comment: Thanks! Last question, for the analytical expression of the derivative wrt param `A` why should that be negative?

Comment: Because at the end your function is `residuals = I_obs - model`, you would get the same, with positive gradients if you used `residuals = model - I_obs`

Comment: I know you are right because it works, but I don't get it from a calculus perspective. Ignoring the squares I have `A*exp(-x0/s)` when I derive wrt `x0` I get `-A*exp(-x0/s)*1` but when I derive wrt A I should not get the minus in front no?

Comment: I made it a bit clearer here https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vvr29uo6dr . As you can see only `g(x)` (derivative wrt `x0`) has a minus in front while `q(x)` (derivative wrt `sigma`) and `a(x)` (derivative wrt `A`) do not have a minus sign, but all of your `grad` terms are without a minus sign.

Comment: Ok wait, probably I understood, is it becuase `x0 = xx - mu`and we are interested in the derivative wrt `mu` which would cancel out the minus sign right? Yes that was it sorry about that, I fixed it now https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vvr29uo6dr