# Search Direction with Scipy.optimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

Is there a simple way to get few search directions (e.g., LBFGS, Truncated-Newton) from `Scipy`? I don't need the full method, just a single search direction. I was thinking about calling directly `scipy.optimize.minimize` with the parameter `maxiter=1` and obtain the direction by difference with the actual point, but I guess I will obtain a direction scaled by the step size in that case, right?

Comment: I think [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#:~:text=The%20gradient%20of%20H%20at,magnitude%20of%20the%20gradient%20vector.) is what you are looking for.

Comment: No, I am looking for a second order direction in the case of LBFGS or a combination of congjugate directions in the case of Truncated-Newton solved with CG, or in general other directions

Comment: So I would go like you mentioned, or just keep track of the parameters given to your objective function for multiple calls, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66494932/how-to-calculate-relative-error-in-the-sum-of-squares-and-relative-error-in-t/66552138#66552138). I think this is a purpose different to what the method was designed, so I fear there is no standard mechanism, but in python you always can cheat :)